Uniqueness in Hensel's lemma
Henri Cohen's "A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory contains the following variant of Hensel's lemma.

Theorem 3.5.3. Let $p$ be a prime, and let $C,A_e,B_e,U,V$ be polynomials with integer coefficients and satisfying
$$
C(X) \equiv A_e(X)B_e(X) \mod p^e, \quad U(X)A_e(X) + V(X)B_e(X) \equiv 1 \mod p.
$$
Assume that $e \geq 1$, $A_e$ is monic, $\deg(U) < \deg(B_e)$, $\deg(V) < \deg(A_e)$. Then there exist polynomials $A_{e+1}$ and $B_{e+1}$ satisfying the same conditions with $e$ replaced by $e+1$, and such that
$$
A_{e+1}(X) \equiv A_e(X) \mod p^e, \quad B_{e+1}(X) \equiv B(X) \mod p^e.
$$
Furthermore, these polynomials are unique modulo $p^{e+1}$.

The proof starts as follows:
Let $D = (C-A_eB_e)/p^e$.
Clearly, $A_{e+1}$ and $B_{e+1}$ have to be of the form $A_{e+1} = A_e + p^eS$, $B_{e+1} = B_e + p^eT$ for some $S,T \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$.
Such $S$ and $T$ yield $A_{e+1}, B_{e+1}$ satisfying $C \equiv A_{e+1}B_{e+1} \mod p^{e+1}$ iff $$C \equiv A_eB_e + p^e(A_eT+B_eS) \mod p^{e+1}$$ and equivalently iff $$A_eT + B_eS \equiv D \mod p.$$
Up until this point, everything is clear to me.
However, Cohen states that $S$ and $T$ have to form $S \equiv VD + WA_e \mod p$ and $T \equiv UD - WB_e \mod p$ for some polynomial $W$. I do understand that such $S$ and $T$ indeed yield $A_{e+1}, B_{e+1}$ with $C \equiv A_{e+1}B_{e+1} \mod p^e$, since
$$
A_eT+B_eS \equiv A_eUD - A_eWB_e + B_eVD +B_eWA_e \equiv D \mod p,
$$
As required. However, I do not understand the following:
Question: Why can't there be $S$ and $T$ of a different shape?
Cohen writes that $S$ and $T$ have to be of this form

since $U(X)A_e(X) + V(X)B_e(X) = 1$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ and $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a field.

Unfortunately, I don't see how this implies that $S$ and $T$ must have this particular shape.

@Afntu's answer is good, so let me just give you are more conceptual answer with less details.
In the step you are looking at, you are essentially just using Bézout's Identity for polynomials over a field (which is why the author points this out). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity#For_polynomials.
In this case, it works exactly like in the integers. By your second equation, you see that $A_e$ and $B_e$ are relatively prime in $\Bbb{F}_p[x]$, with a solution to Bézout given by $(U,V)$. Then, just like in the integers, you know that all other solutions will have the form $(U+QB_e,V+QA_e)$ for some polynomial $Q$ (here we use that they are relatively prime). Since $(S,T)$ is a solution to $A_eS+B_eT= D$, they must then have the form above, multiplied by $D$, i.e.
$$(S,T) = (UD-DQB_e, VD+DQA_e),$$
and writing $W=DQ$, this is exactly what the author claims. Uniqueness follows as there is essentially only one choice of $Q$ such that the polynomials on the right hand side have degree strictly less than $B_e$ and $A_e$, respectively.

I am trying to elaborate on this proof, hoping this will help you.
As $C = A_eB_e \bmod{p^{e}}$, so we have one $D(X) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $C = A_eB_e + p^{e}D$
It is very natural to choose, $A_{e+1} = A_e + p^eS$, $B_{e+1} = B_e + p^eT$ for some $S,T \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$.
We have to find this $S$ and $T$ which satisfies $C \equiv A_{e+1}B_{e+1} \mod p^{e+1}$ iff $$C \equiv A_eB_e + p^e(A_eT+B_eS) \mod p^{e+1}$$ and equivalently iff $$A_eT + B_eS \equiv D \mod p.$$
Also it is given that, $U(X)A_e(X) + V(X)B_e(X) \equiv 1 \mod p$
Consider then two polynomials, $\hat{S} = VD$ and $\hat{T} = UD$, it is clear that it satisfies $A_eT + B_eS \equiv D \mod p$, as $A_e\hat{T} + B_e\hat{S} = A_{e}UD + B_{e}VD \equiv D \mod p$.
But the only problem is that we have no control over the degree of $\hat{S}$, because if the degree is more significant than $\deg A_e$ then $A_{e+1} = A_e + p^{e}\hat{S}$ will not be monic of $\deg A_{e}$.
To solve this issue, divide $\hat{S}$ by $A_{e}$, then by division algorithm, we get $\hat{S} = A_{e}W + S$, where $S$ is the remainder, and $W$ is the quotient. So, obviously $\deg S(x) < \deg A_{e}(x)$.
So we assume $S = VD - A_{e}W$ and now if we set $T = UD + B_{e}W$, then it all works out:
$A_eT+B_eS \equiv A_eUD + A_eB_eW + B_eVD - B_eA_eW \equiv D \mod p$, which implies that $C \equiv A_{e+1}B_{e+1} \mod p^{e+1}$ and $A_{e+1}(X) \equiv A_e(X) \mod p^e, \quad B_{e+1}(X) \equiv B(X) \mod p^e.$
Finally we can observe that $U(X)A_{e+1}(X) + V(X)B_{e+1}(X) \equiv U(X)A_{e}(X) + V(X)B_{e}(X) \equiv 1 \bmod{p}$.
So $A_{e+1}$ and $B_{e+1}$ is relatively prime in the field $\mathbb{F}_{p}$. Interestingly, the same $U, V$ works to show this Bezou't identity.
